# how to refactor this jQuery(only AJAX URL different)

Tags: jquery, refactoring

```
function one(R) {
  # do some thing..
  $.ajax({
    'url': '/one?search=' + R.val(),
  #some thing common here

}

function two(R) {
  # do some thing..
  $.ajax({
    'url': '/two?search=' + R.val(),
  #some thing common here

}
```

well, since I'm just doing jQuery, but I guess this can get improve, refactor?

Answer (score 1):

```
function search(value, url) {
    $.ajax({url: '/'+url+'?search='+val});
};

search(elem.val(), 'one');
```

or

```
$.fn.search = function(url) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $.ajax({url:'/'+url+'?search='+$(this).val()});
    });
}

$('input').search('one');
```

Answer (score 0):

sure you can,

```
function one(R, url) {
  # do some thing..
  $.ajax({
    'url': url + R.val(),
  #some thing common here
}
```

you might tell us why, what you want to do, and give us some morge code (where does the R come from etc). We might be able to give you more information